# linked list search function

Tags: c, linked-list, unused-variables

I am developing a C program and I want to use this function to check if an element of type **Client** with a given **number** is already inserted. It moves along the list and **returns 1** as soon as the number is found, only when I try to compile, it tells me the "**prev**" variable is not used.

```
int list_search_number(LinkedListNode head, Client value){                      
    LinkedListNode prev, curr;

    prev = NULL;
    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) { 
          if(curr->value.number!=value.number){ 
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;}                   
          else if(curr->value.number==value.number)
            return 1;                                
    }      
return 0;                           
}
```

The linked list and Client structures are defined correctly.

Comment: how is LinkedListNode defined? I would have expected a "pointer to LinkedListNode" for the head argument to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to store `prev` pointer since there is no need for it. Remove prev variable and go on.

Change the algorithm to return 1 if the number is found and return 0 if it is not found. prev pointer is useless.

Here is the code.

```
int list_search_number(LinkedListNode head, Client value){                      
    LinkedListNode curr;


    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) { 
          if(curr->value.number==value.number){ 
            return 1;
            }                   
          else {
                curr = curr->next;      
            }                      
    }      
return 0;                           
}
```